# The loop of the strncpy function is not understood

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, char, strncpy

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *source, size_t n) {
  char *start = dest;

  while (n && (*dest++ = *source++)) n--;
// I don't understand from the code below this
// I know I put'\0' at the end of dest.
// But I don't know how if (n) while (--n) works.
  if (n) while (--n) *dest++ = '\0';
  return start;
}
```

http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/lib/string.c.html#:38

Comment: Please provide a brief description of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylistic decisions of this code make it difficult for a newer developer to read. A quick run through a beautifier gives this result (with my own comments added).

```c
//takes a destination string, a source string, and a size (count) of characters to copy
char * strncpy(char * dest, const char * source, size_t n) {

  //create a pointer to the start of the destination string
  char * start = dest;

  //run this loop until one of two things happens: 
  //- n hits 0, meaning we've copied the required number of characters
  //- the assignment operator '=' returns '\0', indicating that we've just copied
  //  a '\0' into dest - this means we've hit the last character in source.
  while (n && ( * dest++ = * source++)) {
    n--;
  }

  //this checks to see if n still has leftover value - if it does, it means that
  //source had fewer characters than we were asked to copy
  if (n) {
    //we will now go through the remaining characters and pad the returned string
    while (--n) {
      //add '\0' to the return string
      * dest++ = '\0';
    }
  }

  return start;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This loops

```
while (n && (*dest++ = *source++)) n--;
```

has two sub-expressions in the condition expression.

The first one is the sub-expression `n` that can be equivalently rewritten like `n != 0`.

So if n is not equal to 0 then the second sub-expression `(*dest++ = *source++)` is evaluated that copies character pointed to by the pointer source to the element of the destination array pointed to by the pointer `dest`.

You can imaging this sub-expression

```
(*dest++ = *source++)
```

as the following sequence of operations

```
( *dest = *source++, *dest++ != '\0' )
```

The result of the expression is value of the character that is copied. So if the copied character is not the terminating zero character `'\0'` then the logical value of the sub-expression is true. Otherwise it is false because is equal to zero `('\0')`.

So this loop either copies n characters or if a zero-character was encountered then all characters before this zero terminating character including the zero terminating character itself.

The next loop appends the destination string with zeroes until the expression `--n` is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

That function is a bit obfuscated with how it deals with the value of `n`.

But, I suppose you know what `if (...) { something; }` works, and that it doesn't need the braces if there's just one statement inside?

```
if (n) while (--n) *dest++ = '\0';
```

is just a `while` nested inside an `if`, it's exactly the same as:

```
if (n) {
   while (--n) {
      *dest++ = '\0';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `while` loop copies at most `n` characters from `source` to `dest`. This loop stops when `n == 0`, or `(*dest++ = *source++)` evaluates to NUL (`'\0'`), meaning the end of the source string has been found.

Then `n` is tested to see if there are still expected operations - that is, the caller expected more characters to be copied, but the `source` string ended early. The second loop fulfills this by placing NUL bytes, padding `dest` to match the size of `n`.